# Elastic Beanstalk with multiple environments and URL routing between them

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices

I'm trying to get started with creating a website with a few Docker microservices using Amazon Web Services. These services should all reside under the same domain, so i want something like:

- *domain.com/search* to point to my *Search* service.
- *domain.com/auth* to point to my *Authentication* service.
- *domain.com/static* to point to a bucket of static files.
- *domain.com* to point to */static/index.html* (which implements an AngularJS app).

(note: everything under the mentioned directories should also point to the particular service, ie. */search/autocomplete* points to *Search*).

*Search* and *Authentication* should both have load balancing independent of each other. These services each implement a web-api in Python/Falcon, and the containers are set up to listen on port 80 using a webserver embedded in the container.

I would also like to have *Search* be able to invoke *Authentication*.

I'm very confused as how to go about this. I'm not even sure Elastic Bealstalk is the right tool to use, so i was hoping to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you.